# No data being returned from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

My ApiController is supposed to return data:

```
// GET api/profile
public IEnumerable<HubBasicProfile> GetProjectProfiles()
{
    IEnumerable<HubBasicProfile> res = _bpss.GetAllBasicProfiles();
    return res;
}
```

When I debug and inspect `res` before it is returned, it has data for 91 `HubBasicProfile` objects.

However, when the data is returned, I see 91 `{}`, empty objects. No data at all.

Anybody any clue why this might be?

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call the `ToList()` method. So [deferred](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx) execution won't happen.

```
public IEnumerable<HubBasicProfile> GetProjectProfiles()
{
    IEnumerable<HubBasicProfile> res = _bpss.GetAllBasicProfiles();
    return res.ToList();
}
```

> Deferred execution means that the evaluation of an expression is
>   delayed until its realized value is actually required
>   collection.

**EDIT :** As per the comment

If you are serializing these items, You need to make sure your class is marked as serializable / has the  [`DataMember]`/ `[DataContract]` Attributes.

Comment: I just did that and no luck. Still no data.

Comment: I am wondering, could it be that whatever serializes it is broken?

Comment: IS your class seriablizable ?

Comment: I meant along the lines of json/xml serializers.

Comment: When I copy and pasted from another class, I also copied [DataContract] but then had no attributes marked as data items. If you hadn't asked about my class being serializable, I wouldn't have seen it. THANKS!

Comment: @Eric : Cool. I will update the answer to include that so that it will help other people in future.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine this is because IEnumerable will use lazy evaluation and isn't being asked to enumerate over it's collection.

When you're debugging, you're telling the debugger to enumerate over 'res' so seeing the results.

If you do a .ToList() or similar before returning, do you see the results?

Comment: I just did that and no luck. Still no data.

Comment: I did think as I wrote the above, that actually it was unlikely to be the lazy evaluation as you were seeing 91 empty objects, rather than zero empty object! turns out I was right! :P glad you got a solution